# ElasticSearch/Logstash: dynamic mapping is wrong

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have installed ES cluster and Logstash.
I have a lot of input types of messages. For now I have problem with Gelf input type. I need to store all fields in ES as string, but if I have json inside gelf "message" field - ES creates new mappings from this json. I don't want it and I tried a lot of variants to disable dynamic mapping for "message" field.
Logstash template config:

```
 {
   "mappings":{
      "_default_":{
         "_all":{
            "enabled":false
         },
         "_source":{
            "enabled":true,
            "compress":true
         },
         "dynamic_templates":[
            {
               "message_template":{
                  "mapping":{
                     "index":"not_analyzed",
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "match":"message",
                  "match_mapping_type":"string"
               },
               "string_template":{
                  "mapping":{
                     "index":"not_analyzed",
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "match":"*",
                  "match_mapping_type":"string"
               }
            }
         ],
         "properties":{
            "@version":{
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "type":"long"
            },
            "@timestamp":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "message":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "dynamic":false
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings":{
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_ops":50000,
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_size":1073741824,
      "refresh_interval":30,
      "number_of_replicas":0,
      "number_of_shards":1
   },
   "template":"gelf-*"
}
```

And logstash output:

```
output {
  if [type] == "gelf" {
    elasticsearch {
      index => 'logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}'
      protocol => http
      template_name => 'logstash-*'
      workers => 4
      template_overwrite => true
      template => '/etc/logstash/index-template.json'
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      index => 'logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}'
      protocol => http
      template_name => 'gelf-*'
      workers => 4
      template_overwrite => true
      template => '/etc/logstash/gelf-template.json'
    }
  }
}
```

When new message with json inside "message" field is received I have mapping on ES:
http://pastebin.com/R9Ei3zEK